# SSRS BIDS expression language Month Part from Current date

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bids, ssrs-expression

In `BIDS` I need an `expression` to take the **YEAR** part of a date which is minus 1 month of the current date.

**For example** Today's date is `20/04/2012` the desired expression would return:

***2012***

If todays date was `05/01/2012` the desured expression would return:

***2011***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the rule is:

- If it's January -> return last year
- else -> return this year

Right?

```
=IIf(Datepart("m", Fields!date.Value)=1,Datepart("YYYY", Fields!date.Value)-1,Datepart("YYYY", Fields!date.Value))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION YearRollOver 
(

    @dDateIn DATETIME
)
RETURNS DATETIME

AS

BEGIN

    declare @dDATEOut  DATETIME


    SELECT @dDATEOut = CAST(CAST(YEAR(@dDateIn)+1 AS varchar)+'/'+CAST(MONTH(@dDateIn) as varchar)+'/'+cast(DAY(@dDateIn) as varchar)  AS DATETIME)

    RETURN @dDATEOut

END
GO
```

Try this function. Just pass it the date to increment and it will up your YEAR by 1.

Remember to close the thread if you are happy.

Cheers

Mac

Comment: he wants a function in SSRS, not in SQl Server.

Comment: Your function has a few problems: first, it doesn't give OP what he wants: the current year if not January other wise last. Yours always give next year. And parsing datetimes to strings for date manipulation in SQL is not so great: for the function you show, why wouldn't you just `DATEADD(year, 1, @dDateIn)` to get the same results?

Answer (score 0):

If its something you are gong to do a lot of I would create a function to do this which would extract the year, month , and day - each to its own var. Increment the Year, rebuild the date as a string and CAST the string as DATE. If you need a hand let me know.

Mac